# At what time User.Identity.IsAuthenticated set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

In my login.aspx page i used `<asp:Login>` control and i need to assign some value if User.Identity.IsAuthenticated= true.

As mentioned in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) When a user submits his or her login information, the Login control first raises the LoggingIn event, then the Authenticate event, and finally the LoggedIn event.

so i checked this value as follows:

```
protected void Login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0;
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        x = 5;
 }
```

But this value is always **false**. My questions are as follows:

1. In which event does this value change to true?
2. what did i do wrong in here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user enters their credentials and clicks the Login button. A postback occurs.

1.The incoming request enters the ASP.NET pipeline.

2.The Application_Authenticate event fires. At this point, the ASP.NET runtime doesn't know who the user is, so User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false

3.The login page's lifecycle beings,

4.The Login control's Authenticate event fires and a forms authentication ticket is created because you set e.Authenticated to true.

5.The Login control's LoggedIn event fires. At this point, we're still on the same request, so User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false!

More Information, read this link :
http://forums.asp.net/t/1177741.aspx?User+Identity+IsAuthenticated+remains+false+why+

Comment: +1 and I'll add that, at a minimum you can get the username from the control (e.g. "Login1.UserName") and do further user-based work before the page closes out and returns to its ReturnUrl.